# Animation transitions not working with external JSON data in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, gsap

I'm getting used to working with Handlebars and JSON. I've created a basic handlebars template and used getJSON for loading the JSON file data. The data shows up fine, but I'm also using gsap for transitions and that does not work. I tried using Gulp for a local server and it still isn't working. However, gsap has no problem in any browser when the data is not in an external JSON file. Should I be loading the JSON another way? Thank you for your help, the snippets are below.

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="example-template">
    {{#each exampleData}}
    <div>
      <div>
          <img data-img src="{{imgSource}}" title="{{imageName}}" /> 
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2 class="title-text">{{title}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>  
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var template = $('#example-template').html();

  var exampleCompile = Handlebars.compile(template);

  $.getJSON('data/test-data.json', function(result){
      $('#container').html(exampleCompile(result));
  });

});

$(function(){

  var imageTransition = new TimelineMax();
  imageTransition
    .staggerFrom('[data-img]', 1, { y: 100 }, 0.25);

  var titleTransition = new TimelineMax();
  titleTransition
    .fromTo('.title-text', 1, {yPercent: -20, autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.8},{yPercent: 0, display: 'block', autoAlpha: 1, scale: 1, ease: Power4.easeIn}, '0'); 

});
```

JSON:

```
{
"exampleData": [
  {
    "imgSource": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-json-data/can.svg",
    "imageName": "can1",
    "title": "Can 1"
  },
  {
    "imgSource": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-json-data/can.svg",
    "imageName": "can2",
    "title": "Can 2"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Try moving all of that animation code into the `getJSON` success handler, after setting the HTML of `$('#container')`.

Comment: @76484, you were right. That fixed it. Thanks!